# How to get the id of navigation drawer button?

Tags: android

How do I find out the id of the navigation drawer button?

[image]

Comment: Navigation button mean this menu like button id?

Comment: Yeah correct. As shown in picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can get the id of the navigation drawer button, but you can get an instance variable for it:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawerLayout,
        toolbar, 
        R.string.drawer_open, 
        R.string.drawer_close 
        );
```

`drawer_layout` is the id of the `DrawerLayout`  
`toolbar` is the id of the `Toolbar`  
and you must create in `strings.xml` the 2 strings `drawer_open` and `drawer_close` with values say: `"Open Drawer"` and `"Close Drawer"`

Then you have access to the drawer button with the variable `drawerToggle`

Comment: how " you have access to the drawer button with the variable drawerToggle"?